# changing search result from only excerpt to full content

Tags: search

i am using canvas theme ,
this is how content-search.php look like

```
<?php
/**
 * Post Content Template
 *
 * This template is the default page content template. It is used to display the content of the
 * `single.php` template file, contextually, as well as in archive lists or search results.
 *
 * @package WooFramework
 * @subpackage Template
 */

/**
 * Settings for this template file.
 *
 * This is where the specify the HTML tags for the title.
 * These options can be filtered via a child theme.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Filters
 */

$settings = array(
                'thumb_w' => 100,
                'thumb_h' => 100,
                'thumb_align' => 'alignleft',
                'post_content' => 'excerpt',
                'comments' => 'both'
                );

$settings = woo_get_dynamic_values( $settings );

$title_before = '<h1 class="title entry-title">';
$title_after = '</h1>';

if ( ! is_single() ) {
    $title_before = '<h2 class="title entry-title">';
    $title_after = '</h2>';
$title_before = $title_before . '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) ) . '" rel="bookmark" title="' . the_title_attribute( array( 'echo' => 0 ) ) . '">';
$title_after = '</a>' . $title_after;
}

$page_link_args = apply_filters( 'woothemes_pagelinks_args', array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'woothemes' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) );

woo_post_before();
?>
<article <?php post_class(); ?>>
<?php
    woo_post_inside_before();
    if ( 'content' != $settings['post_content'] && ! is_singular() )
        woo_image( 'width=' . esc_attr( $settings['thumb_w'] ) . '&height=' . esc_attr( $settings['thumb_h'] ) . '&class=thumbnail ' . esc_attr( $settings['thumb_align'] ) );
?>
    <header>
        <?php the_title( $title_before, $title_after ); ?>
    </header>
<?php
    woo_post_meta();
?>
    <section class="entry">
        <?php
             the_excerpt();
        ?>
    </section><!-- /.entry -->
    <div class="fix"></div>
<?php
    woo_post_inside_after();
?>
</article><!-- /.post -->
<?php
woo_post_after();
$comm = $settings['comments'];
if ( ( 'post' == $comm || 'both' == $comm ) && is_single() ) { comments_template(); }
?>
```

and this is my search.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Search Template
 *
 * The search template is used to display search results from the native WordPress search.
 *
 * If no search results are found, the user is assisted in refining their search query in
 * an attempt to produce an appropriate search results set for the user's search query.
 *
 * @package WooFramework
 * @subpackage Template
 */

 get_header();
 global $woo_options;
?>      
    <!-- #content Starts -->
    <?php woo_content_before(); ?>
    <div id="content" class="col-full">

        <div id="main-sidebar-container">    

            <!-- #main Starts -->
            <?php woo_main_before(); ?>
            <section id="main" class="col-left">

            <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'search' ); ?>

            </section><!-- /#main -->
            <?php woo_main_after(); ?>

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

        </div><!-- /#main-sidebar-container -->         

        <?php get_sidebar( 'alt' ); ?>       

    </div><!-- /#content -->
    <?php woo_content_after(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

according to your 2nd piece of code you're looking for the loop-search.php.

If you're sure it's using the content-search though  change this line:

```
 <section class="entry">
        <?php
             the_excerpt();
        ?>
    </section><!-- /.entry -->
```

to

```
 <section class="entry">
        <?php
             the_content();
        ?>
    </section><!-- /.entry -->
```

or add more detail to the content:

```
the_content( 'Continue reading ' . get_the_title() );
```

Comment: please mark as answered.

Comment: it's the grey checkbox under vote count to the left of the question.  Thanks again!